# .htaccess data to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

At the start: I have no rights to edit any PHP on site I'm woriking on.

The problem is that old .htaccess get lost:

There is a 2 types of links (I need to write backwards rules):

first: "module-title-id"

That was easy enough:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+).html?$ index.php?mod=$1&id=$3
```

As you see the actual links looks like this "index.php?mod=$1&id=$3"

But I have problem with that one:

"page.html?foo=bar" so I tried something like that:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+).html\?([^/]+)\=([^/]+)$ index.php?mod=$1&$2=$3
```

It's working like this: "index.php?foo=bar"

How can I do that?

The rest looks like this:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase '/'

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+).html?$ index.php?mod=$1&id=$3
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+).html\?([^/]+)\=([^/]+)$ index.php?mod=$1&$2=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)\.html?$ index.php?mod=$1&id=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule  ^(.+?)\.html?$ index.php?mod=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule  ^reservation-save\.html$ reservation.html?t=1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: You're my personal hero. Thanks alot!

Comment: So after "?" everything - key and value is auto-posting to vars?

Comment: You're most welcome. Yes query string gets transferred automatically to new URL.

Comment: anubhava you aren't capturing additional items so the rest of your condition can be removed and simplified to - RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?mod=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: There is another url after reservation.html?t=1 it should go to reservation-save.html to complete.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLong: yes that was a bad copy/paste error on my part.

Comment: Actually it was quite easy: 
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)\.html?$ index.php?mod=$1&act=$2 [L,QSA]

Thanks for help once again!